# Call SSRS by URL pass parameter by label

Tags: reporting-services

There is a SSRS report, with one parameter, I only know its label not the values. So how can I get the report by URL? I know how to render a report with all the parameters set by defaults to Excel. But this report has the parameter not set to default, so I have to manually select a value then run in report manager. And important thing is I don't know the available values for this parameter as I have only browser permission. So can't download rdl, can see the parameters etc as you can imagine. The url method seems only allow you to pass parameter value not parameter label. So is there anyway?

Comment: Why can't you contact the publisher of the report or request access to the report?

Comment: It's complicated, our company divided, the report belongs to the other company, but somehow we are in the same LAN, don't ask me, I don't even completely understand this...We still use that report, two companies but have business together.

Comment: I don't really know how to "reverse engineer" reports and don't think a lot of people tried it. If you have access to the Reporting Services DB, then you could find this information. Anyway, if you can't update the report any more, I would consider it dead and write a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You must use the parameter *value* in the URL, you cannot use the label (unless value and label happen to be the same).

If you don't have access to the report definition then you will need to find someone who does, who can then find where the parameter values are defined and tell you what they are.